# How to configure the Screen Locker

Tags: screen-lock, kde4

I'm using KDE 4 and it locks the screen without warning and then it requires password to unlock, I need a warning before locking as the Gnome before locking the screen it set the screen brightness geting darker and darker, you know the screen is ready to be locked.

Answer (score 1):

At System Settings -> Display and Monitor -> Screen Locker you can choose when to lock and when to lock with password. Also, there you can set a screensaver, so it can be as a warning that your session will soon be locked with password.

If this is not enough, you always can install gnome-screensaver, but it may install some gtk-gnome dependencies, so be aware.